# Relation between shader and UV texture mapping

Tags: opengl-es, shader, glkit

I'm using OpenGL ES + GLKit. I've never been this low-level before in my life so I still have to learn a lot of things. I've developed a Unity games before and you just give it a .obj file and corresponding texture and it's done. (UV mapping happens to be inside the .obj file?)

I want to develop a kind of special Toon Shader with some different characteristics for use with 3D model. So I need to write a vertex shader (.vsh) and fragment shader (.fsh) right?

However, I just know that in order to apply a texture to a model with correct UV coordinate, you have to do this in shader? (am I right?) With "Texture Shader".

So, If I want to both apply the texture with UV mapping **then** apply my special Toon Shader, I have to write both in the same shader? There is no way I can create a plug-and-play Toon shader so I can use it with anything?

As a side question, which file format is a UV coordinate and how can I take that in to a shader program? What kind of attribute variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I need to write a vertex shader (.vsh) and fragment shader (.fsh)
>   right?

Yes.

> However, I just know that in order to apply a texture to a model with
>   correct UV coordinate

True

> There is no way I can create a plug-and-play Toon shader so I can use
>   it with anything?

Check [Uber-Shaders](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/457909-uber-shaders/)

> and how can I take that in to a shader program? What kind of attribute
>   variable?

You are defining your attributes in shader by yourself. Check this [GLSL tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/)

Comment: Don't you just reread your posted answers to find such horrible formatting errors? You could have just seen this from the corner of your eye without even reading anything.

Comment: As a note, uber shaders are a terrible idea in OpenGL ES due to the performance hit from branching. Instead, you really should be crafting separate shaders that fit your particular rendering condition (or do compile-time assembly of such custom shaders) and avoid any sort of branching.

Comment: Uber shaders can be done with defines, not with "if (technique)"